# hide url in statusbar while mouseover a thumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i'm using fancybox for my gallerys and have disabled the right click funktion but i want also hide the url in statusbar while hover over the thumbs.
on other sites i use this code to do it.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href='http:\\my-url.com'">Link</a>
```

with this code i load the gallery

```
echo '<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="' . $config['fulls'] . $imagelist[$i] . '" title="' . $imagelist[$i] . '" >';
    echo '<img src="' . $config['thumbs'] . $imagelist[$i] . '" alt="' . $imagelist[$i] .
        '">';
    echo '</a>';
```

but i cant' hide the url with the above code. if i do use it the same way as on my other sites than fancybox stop working.
may be any one has a suggestion for me?

Thanks

Comment: You know users do not dare to click on those suspicious links. There are a lot of reasons for that e.g. phishing.

Comment: i know. but it's a gallery made for a elementary school. user can view the pics from some schoolevents but if they want the pictures than they have to pay a few bugs to the school. so i want to make sure that no one can get the pics for free by reading the url in the statusbar ;)

Comment: despite you hide the URL from the status bar, you can download any image once it's opened in fancybox

Comment: and how can the images be downloaded? i have disabled 'right click'
maybe there are other methodes to download the mages, but i guess non of the visitors of this site will be able to know how ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancybox v2.x, you could use the `data-fancybox-href` attribute instead of `href` and no link will be shown, like :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-href="images/image01.jpg">open fancybox</a>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/koc5arb5/)**